# php_error: Cannot use positional argument after named argument

Tags: php

`$name = explode( separator: '.', $name );`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQbHi.png)

Here is where my code is wrong. I tried to separate the image name from the image extension but it gives an error, but I think the format of the code is correct, so what is the problem here?

Comment: You may be getting confused by your IDE automatically showing you the name of argument variables.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add `separator:` in the explode statement.

So just use the following:

```
<?php

$name="test.jpg";
$name = explode('.', $name );

//filename (without extension)  (for xxxx.xxxx)
echo $name[0];
echo "<br>";

//extension of the filename (for xxxx.xxxx)
echo $name[1];
?>
```